# jQuery to remove a div if a Bootstrap tab is not active

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, tabs

I want to remove a div (as below), if a Bootstrap tab is not active.

Div to be removed:

```
<div id="myCarousel"> ... </div>
```

Show above div:

```
<li class="overview active">
```

Remove #myCarousel div:

```
<li class="overview">
```

My JavaScript attempt follows below, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#myTab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function ( e) {
          if ( e.target.parent().hasClass('overview.active') )
            jQuery('#myCarousel').show();
          else
            jQuery('#myCarousel').hide();
    });
})
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Km3larFNET)

HTML:

```
 <div id="myCarousel"> sfsdfsdfsdf </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li id="myTab" class="overview active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                if ($("#myTab")[0].className=='overview active')
                    jQuery('#myCarousel').show();
                else
                    jQuery('#myCarousel').hide();
            });
        })
```

Comment: Thank you... that works... just one thing - if I click away from the overview li, then click it back to active the myCarousel div doesn't come back... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(e.target).parent().is('.overview.active');
```

OR

```
$(e.target).parent().hasClass("overview active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hasClass with 'active' only:

```
if( e.target.parent().hasClass( 'active' )
    $("#myCarousel").show();
else 
    $("#myCarousel").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('li').hasClass('active') ){
   jQuery('#myCarousel').show();
 }
else {
 jQuery('#myCarousel').hide();
}
```